# Count PDF pages in constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I have an object that represents a PDF file. In the constructor, I pull out various information about the file name and make it available via properties:

```
public class Invoice
{ 
    //public properties
    public string FullPath {get { return this.fullPath;} }
    public string FileNameWithoutExtension { get { return this.fileNameWithoutExtension;} }
    public string FileName { get { return this.fileName; } }
    public string BatchSequenceNumber { get { return this.batchSequenceNumber; } }

    //private fields
    private string fullPath;
    private string fileNameWithoutExtension;
    private string fileName;
    private string batchSequenceNumber;

    //Default construtor
    public Invoice(string filePath)
    {
        this.fullPath = filePath;
        this.fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        this.fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        this.batchSequenceNumber = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath).Split('_').LastOrDefault();
    }
}
```

One of the attributes I would like to get is the number of pages in the PDF.
I am using `iTextSharp` and I have a `PageCount` method in the above `Invoice` class that looks like this:

```
public int PageCount()
    {
        PdfReader reader = null;
        int pageCount;

        try
        {
            reader = new PdfReader(this.FullPath);
            pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error reading pdf! " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null) { reader.Close(); }
        }

        return pageCount;
    }
```

This works fine, except now I need to get the count of pages at several times during the object lifetime. I do not want to keep opening the PDF each time to get the count so these are my ideas:

1. Rename method `PageCount` to `CountPages` and store the result in field/property `PageCount`.
2. Count the pages in the constructor and store the result in a field/propertry `PageCount` and don't expose a `CountPages` method.

Number 1 seems preferable to me, but what if someone tries to read `PageCount` before running method `CountPages`? How best to handle this situation, set `PageCount` to 0 in the constructor?

Number 2 seems bad because it feels wrong to open the PDF file in the constructor, is it? (I have been reading [this](http://www.daedtech.com/beware-the-bloated-constructor))

Comment: Some others beat me to answering, but I wanted to mention that this is some of the cleaner code we see around here. Good names and simple code. I like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. A constructor shouldn't be *doing* much, other than *constructing* an object.

I also agree that `PageCount` sounds much more like a property than a method... and `CountPages()` would be more appropriate for a method that actually counts pages.

Now, the problem would be that the `PageCount` getter would return `0` until `CountPages()` is called - setting it to `0` in the constructor would only be redundant, since `PageCount` would be an `int` and an `int` gets initialized to `default(int)`, which is `0`.

I think your problem stems from the class doing too many things. I'd introduce a `InvoicePdfLoader` class exposing some `Load(string)` method that returns an immutable `struct`:

```
public class InvoicePdfLoader
{
    public InvoiceInfo Load(string path)
    {
        int pageCount;
        using (var reader = new PdfReader(path)) // assuming PdfReader : IDisposable
        {
            pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages
        }

        return new InvoiceInfo(path, pageCount);
    }
}
```

Notice the `using` block around the `reader` instance: if `PdfReader` implements the `IDisposable` interface, you *need* to properly dispose it. If it doesn't, the way you have it (manually closing it in a `finally` clause) is perfect.

And then `InvoiceInfo` is just a simple, lightweight value type:

```
public struct InvoiceInfo
{
    private readonly string _fullPath;
    private readonly string _fileNameWithoutExtension;
    private readonly string _fileName;
    private readonly string _batchSequenceNumber;
    private readonly int _pageCount;

    public InvoiceInfo(string path, int pageCount)
    {
        _fullPath = path;
        _fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
        _fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        _batchSequenceNumber = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
                                   .Split('_')
                                   .LastOrDefault();
        _pageCount = pageCount;
    }

    public string FullPath { get { return _fullPath; } }
    public string FileNameWithoutExtension { get { return _fileNameWithoutExtension; } }
    public string FileName { get { return _fileName; } }
    public string BatchSequenceNumber { get { return _batchSequenceNumber; } }
    public int PageCount { get { return _pageCount; } }
}
```

I find the name `InvoiceInfo` better conveys the essence of what you're having here - it's not *really* an `Invoice`, rather just some metadata *about* an invoice.

Comment: Ah yes - I have a habit of trying to squeeze as much as possible into a class! Would it make sense for `InvoicePdfLoader` to become a static class?

Comment: As is, it would, but I personally don't like `static` classes much. Being non-static makes classes that depend on it easier to test.

Comment: Also weirdly `PdfReader` does not implement `IDisposable`. I may do try though: `class CustomPDFReader : PdfReader, IDisposable { public void Dispose() { this.Close(); } }` But that's for another question...

Comment: I wouldn't do that, unless the `PdfReader` instance was a private field (which it doesn't need to be) - there's nothing wrong with manually closing it in a `finally` block ;)

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want to avoid opening the file unless necessary (ie until someone requests the PageCount), I would use a nullable private field, as follows:

```
private int? _pageCount;

public int PageCount
{
    get
    {
        if (!_pageCount.HasValue) {
            //existing code to determine page count

            _pageCount = /* result */
        }
        return _pageCount;
    }
}
```

The first time the property is accessed, the private member will be null, so the code to update the value will be run.  Subsequent accesses will use the cached value.

Comment: +1 - the key here is *assuming you want to avoid opening the file unless necessary*.

Comment: Lazy properties is where I'd go with it as well. However, I would join all of these properties together (page count, word count, file size, whatever) in a single initializer to be called when one of the properties is accessed. Otherwise reading n closely related properties will still open/close the document n times.

Comment: Rather than rolling your own lazy behavior, you could use a [Lazy<int>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) field.  `PageCount` would then just return _pageCount.Value;

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't it be better to replace the private field/public property structure with a public property that has a private setter, like this:

```
public string FullPath { get; private set; }
```

Makes the code more concise.

Comment: Good catch! Auto-properties FTW!

Comment: @chazjn do note, however, that a `private readonly` private field conveys *intent* in a more unambiguous way; I wouldn't use such auto-properties in an *immutable* `struct`.